# Loading Images with Glide and FirebaseUI not working with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide, firebaseui

I'm trying to load ProfileImages in a ListView (I know its outdated) by extending BaseAdapter using the Glide method provided in **'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'** package.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui

Here is the getView() method of the Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
...
if (tempProfile != null) {
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("path_to_image");

    **** Problem ****
    Glide.with(context /* context */)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageRef)
            .into(viewHolder.profileImage_IV);
    **** See alternate line of code ****
}
else {
  viewHolder.profileImage_IV.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.no_image));
}
```

****PROBLEM****: The glide line of code **inflates images in ImageView of ALL THE ROWS(a lot of unnecessary rows get iflated by the image)**. The else{} part is able to overwrite a few images but not all the images. And therefore, I get INCORRECT result.

OBSERVATION: But instead of Glide line of code, if I use this line then I get the CORRECT result.

```
viewHolder.profileImage_IV.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.accept));
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is eventContentRef?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Fixed it!

Comment: Did u get duplicate images in a different list position?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the issue I'm having.

Comment: And the storage ref changes according to the list position right?

Comment: Yes. It changes according to the list item position.

Comment: it seems it is a bug in Glide. maybe you can try initialize FirebaseImageLoader in the constructor and use the same instance in Glide. Not sure but may be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug? Is there any link to validate that? Also, initializing FirebaseImageLoader in constructor didn't make any difference

Comment: I am not sure it is just my thought. can you try removing else statement? see this link for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/35114351/5923606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35114351/2937847 .

Basically if you inflate an ImageView using Glide, then you must clear it also using Glide. I had to add just 1 line in else{}

```
else {
    Glide.clear(profileImage_IV);
    viewHolder.profileImage_IV.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.no_image));
}
```